# Failing to append bigger data frames with pandas in nested loops. How to change to numpy vectorization?

Tags: python, pandas, append, vectorization, nested-loops

I need to load a huge table (6 gb) from an older postgres db that contains some bad values that I need to delete on load. So I wrote a loop that tries to load bigger chunks for performance reasons, but reduces step by step to isolate and discard the bad values. Generally this works, but after more or less 500 k records the performance decreases rapidly.

I have already found that it is not advisable to process larger datasets with pandas. That's why I tried to use numpy. But that didn't change anything. Then I tried to use list comprehensions, but failed because of the exceptions I have to use to try to iterate in smaller chunks.

From my point of view numpy vectorisation looks like a good idea, but I have no idea how to make it work.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06

In general this part I'd like to speed up massivley.

```
df = pds.read_sql_query(sql,conn,params=[(i * chunksize), chunksize])
appended_df.append(df)
products_df = pds.concat(appended_df, ignore_index=True)
```

If the snippet above isn't enough context below you'll find even more.

```
# set autocommit = True
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)

cur = conn.cursor()

# count rows for chunking
sql_count = """\
select count("item_no") from "products" 
"""
cur.execute(sql_count)
sql_row_counter = cur.fetchone()[0]
print("Total rows: " + str(sql_row_counter))

# define chunksize and calculate chunks
chunksize = 35000
chunk_divisor = 100
if chunksize / chunk_divisor < 1:
    chunk_divisor = chunksize
print("Chunk devisor on error: " + str(chunk_divisor))
chksz_lvl2 = int(chunksize / chunk_divisor)
if chksz_lvl2 < 1:
    chksz_lvl2 = 1
chksz_lvl3 = int(chksz_lvl2 / chunk_divisor)
if chksz_lvl3 < 1:
    chksz_lvl3 = 1
# print settings for iteration
print("Chunksize: " + str(chunksize) + "\nChunksize Level 2: " +
       str(chksz_lvl2) + "\nChunksize Level 3: " + str(chksz_lvl3))
chunks = int(sql_row_counter / chunksize)
# Uncomment next row for testpurposes
chunks = 25
print("Chunks: " + str(chunks) + "\n")
error_counter = 0
# iterate chunks
appended_df = []
print("Starting to iterate chunks.\nPlease wait...")

for i in range(0, chunks):
            # try to iterate in full speed
            print("\nNext chunk starts from " + str((i * chunksize)) +
                  " with an limit of " + str(chunksize) + ".")
            try:
                # start runtime measurment
                i_start = time.time()
                # sql statement
                sql = """\
                select "item_no", "description_1", "description_2", "description_3" FROM "products" order by "item_no" offset ? limit ?"""
                # store into dataframe
                df = pds.read_sql_query(sql,
                                        conn,
                                        params=[(i * chunksize), chunksize])
                # get first and last value from dataframe
                head = df["item_no"].iloc[0]
                tail = df["item_no"].iloc[-1]
                # store query
                # Appending data frames via pandas.append() suddenly becomes slower by a factor of 10 from approx. 500,000 data records per 4 columns.
                appended_df.append(df)
                # stop runtime measurement
                i_end = time.time()
                # print result
                print(
                    str(i + 1) + " out of " + str(chunks) + " chunks in " +
                    "{:5.3f}s".format(i_end - i_start) + " processed.")
            except:
                # collect error information
                print(
                    "\nChunk " + str(i + 1) +
                    " cannot be selected due to an error. Reduce chunk size from "
                    + str(chunksize) + " to " + str(chksz_lvl2) +
                    ". Entering level 2.\nFirst working item_no of last working chunk "
                    + str(head) +
                    "\nLast working item_no of last working chunk " +
                    str(tail))
                ### 2 ### Successively reduce the chunks to narrow down and isolate errors.
                for j in range(0, chunk_divisor):
                     
                  and so on...
                             ...
                                ...
                                   ...
# Merge chunks
print("\nNote: Chunkzize = from row_no to row_no. Could be 1,2,3,4 = range of 4 or compleley different. Ex. 2,45,99,1002 = range of 4.\n\nConcatinate chunks.")
products_df = pds.DataFrame()
products_df = pds.concat(appended_df, ignore_index=True)
print("Done. " + str(error_counter) +
" rows had to be skipped. Details can be found in the full error log.")

conn.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried to look on the side of dask ? https://dask.org/

Comment: What 'bad values' are you trying to deal with? All I see is a bare except in case of any arbitrary problem.

Comment: Somehow colleagues managed to get values into the database that cannot be encoded by utf8 and win1250, which is mandatory. These interfere with the select. Have already adjusted at various places, for example at the driver etc.. This way is the most stable so far. Therefore I would like to follow it. In 500,000 records only a handful are problematic.

I have not yet heard of Dask. I am not a native developer and therefore stumble piece by piece into the topic. :)

Comment: @Tbaki
I've now tried to swith to dask. In general dask is in use now but nothing has changed regarding perfomance. 
`df = pds.read_sql_query(sql,conn,params=[(i * chunksize), chunksize])
dask_df = from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)
appended_df.append(dask_df)
products_df = multi.concat(appended_df, ignore_index=True)
products_df=products_df.compute()`

Comment: @HoneyCodeBadger wierd, dask shouldn't be affected by the GIL(Global Interpreter Lock), worse case scenario, launch different python program on different chunk to really cut down the time.

Comment: @Tbaki do you know if it's a porblem useing dask in loops (4 deeper lvl in total)? Because at the moment I run the loops and select some data via pandas from sql dureing these loops. Then I convert it to a dask df. After this I append the dask df to an dask df. After all iterations were done I convert back to pandas and write into sql. I tried switching the appending to multi.concat as well. But this is even slower. I also thought about multi threading the whole loop but I'm a bit unsure how to deal with the dependencies between the loops to calculate the correct params for the sql statement.

Comment: @HoneyCodeBadger No ideas, dask is supposed to parralelize task done within the dask frame and method, From what you said, it's the concat that take more time than the operation you're doing with it ? If that the case, try to get the numpy under it (df.values) and concat that instead before creating your dataframe. Or push the numpy directly to you database.

Comment: @Tbaki exactly. It's only the part of appending the dataframe to another. I already tried `np.append() instead` of `pd.append()`.Did you mean that? Based on your tipp I've tried the explained above. Speed is always the same at the same time. It works well close to 500 k of records. But not exactly to 500.000. And then it get's slow rapidly from the one loop to the other. I tried to switch from `dd.append` to `dd.multi.concat()` inbetwen the loops as well. But then it get's even slower.

Comment: @HoneyCodeBadger if your purpose is to concatenate data, maybe the best way if to write into a text file, and apprend your data in a csv formating, that way you don't need to do two time the work. You can then load the entire dataset as you see fit.

Comment: @Tbaki thanks for your support on this. I've recently noticed by chance that the issue is outside my script. I'll post this as an answer. I appreaciate your feedback.

Comment: @Tbaki I was able to load 1.4 mio reccords within 20 min. There's still some place to improve but in general it's already fine. Therefore I can finaly confirm, YES IT WORKS. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just noticed that the python script is already running as expected. Other frameworks like Dask haven't had any chance to improve this. In my case the source Postgres DB (in my case v. 9.x) where I'd like to get some data has an issue regarding the usage of `limit` and `order by` at the same time during querying huge tables.

I was not able to detect this directly, because my SQL query tool (DBeaver) only loads a subset to display even if you want to query the full table. Therefor the result is a false friend. If you want to check properly run a short select with an pretty huge `offset` and `limit` via ordering.

With an offset of approx. 500 k of records the time to select of only one record took about 10 sec in my case.

The solution was to remove the `order by` in my embedded SQL script at the "try" part.